# Error in Azure function - Host lock lease acquired by instance ID '0000000000000000000000006000A33F'

Tags: azure-functions

I am getting this error when running Azure function locally.
**Host lock lease acquired by instance ID '0000000000000000000000006000A33F'**

I have been getting this error after I cleared all the temp storages. (temp, %temp%) etc..

Does anyone face this kind of issue?  Looking for someone's help.
Thank you in advance.

Comment: Actually the  "Host lock lease acquired by instance ID '0000000000000000000000006000A33F'" is not an error message, so can you put the whole error message and your code?

Comment: Does this GitHub issue answer your question - https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-host/issues/611

Comment: @DorisLv -  so is this message expected?
Actually my azure function is cosmos db triggered one and I think I'm not passing the lease name. The same cosmos collection is being listened by some other processor as well.
So could you please let me know how do we define the lease name/identity so that the same cosmos collection change feed can trigger at both places (processor and Azure function)?

Comment: Yes, this message is expected. Your function is working, but as you said, you didn't configure the trigger correctly. Here is a tutorial you can refer to: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-create-cosmos-db-triggered-function

Comment: @DorisLv - I've figured out the way for multiple listeners for the same collection. 
So we need to include the LeaseCollectionPrefix parameter in the function.

Comment: Hi, @Amarjeet Kumar. if the solution did some help, do you mind accepting it as the answer for others to refer?

Comment: @DorisLv - sorry for the slow reply. Yes... it helped. accepted it as an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. The message `Host lock lease acquired by instance ID '0000000000000000000000006000A33F'` is not an error message, it's an
   expected message, which means your function is working and waiting
   for triggering.
2. Here is the [Microsoft docs described Azure Cosmos DB bindings for
   Function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-cosmosdb?tabs=csharp).

   Use `ConnectionStringSetting` to connect Function with Cosmos DB
   like below:

   ```
   [FunctionName("DocumentUpdates")]
       public static void Run(
           [CosmosDBTrigger("database", "collection", ConnectionStringSetting = "myCosmosDB")]
       IReadOnlyList<Document> documents,
           TraceWriter log)
       {
           ...
       }
   ```
3. If you are pretty new to this, you can go to this [tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-create-cosmos-db-triggered-function)
   first.