# Cloud functions - Host instance 'xxxxxxxxxxxxx' failed to acquire host lock lease: Azure.Storage.Blobs

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-storage, azure-storage-account

I have a function app attached to a storage account with 3 functions with timer triggers that randomly stopped working since last month.

Any pointers to troubleshoot?

Log stream pasted below

> 2022-06-09T03:19:21Z [Information] Retrying to start listener for
> function 'Functions.MonthlyTriggerTotal' (Attempt 18)
> 2022-06-09T03:19:21Z [Information] Retrying to start listener for
> function 'Functions.TimerTrigger1' (Attempt 18) 2022-06-09T03:19:21Z
> [Information] Retrying to start listener for function
> 'Functions.RecurringExpensesTrigger' (Attempt 18) 2022-06-09T03:19:21Z
> [Verbose] Host instance 'xxxx-xxx-xxxxxxxxx' failed to acquire host
> lock lease: Azure.Storage.Blobs: Server failed to authenticate the
> request. Make sure the value of Authorization header is formed
> correctly including the signature.
> RequestId:d859920b-901e-0035-40af-7b9e9a000000
> Time:2022-06-09T03:19:21.2193397Z Status: 403 (Server failed to
> authenticate the request. Make sure the value of Authorization header
> is formed correctly including the signature.) ErrorCode:
> AuthenticationFailed
>
> Additional Information: AuthenticationErrorDetail: The MAC signature
> found in the HTTP request 'xxx-xxxx-xxx-xxxx' is not the same as any
> computed signature. Server used following string to sign: 'PUT

Answer (score 0):

> Retrying to start listener for function 'Functions.TimerTrigger1

- AFAIK this issue not a problem in function app or platform which you have deployed as it is not synchronized properly.
- Make sure your triggers are synchronized properly, try to disable, and enable in app setting and click refresh next to your app name.
- Please check your time zone which you have configured in timer trigger function. If you must modify the same in it, use `WEBSITE_TIME_ZONE` setting. Also, check your desktop time too.

Please check this related [answer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/548467/azure-function-timer-trigger-suddenly-stops-firing.html) provided by **MayankBargali-MSFT**

> *Timer triggered function app uses* [*TimerTriggerAttribute*](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-timer?tabs=csharp#attributes-and-annotations)*. This attribute consists of* [*Singleton Lock*](https://github.com/Azure/azure-webjobs-sdk-extensions/wiki/TimerTrigger#singleton-locks) feature which can run a single instance of function at given time. If you are using the same storage account with different timer trigger functions, try to disable them by using_ *UseMonitor = false* *on your TimerTrigger attribute.*

- Try to check the connection of `local.settings.json` for every function running locally.
- Make sure you should not enable **runOnStartup** to true
- Check whether the other two function apps uses time trigger to the same identifying configuration, only one timer can run.

> If you are using azure function in cosmos db triggered, refer  this
> [So
> thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63803777/error-in-azure-function-host-lock-lease-acquired-by-instance-id-0000000000000)  by **Doris Lv**

Please check this issue via running on [Azure Functions diagnostics](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-diagnostics),   if the issue still persists please raise  [azure support ticket](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/support/create-ticket/) to guides you right information

For your Reference :

https://github.com/Azure/azure-webjobs-sdk-extensions/wiki/TimerTrigger#troubleshooting

https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-host/wiki/Investigating-and-reporting-issues-with-timer-triggered-functions-not-firing